# PHP fwrite doesn't appear to be writing or ftp_fput is messing up?

Tags: php, file-upload, file-io, ftp

I have the following code

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.MYSITE.com") or die("Failed to connect to FTP server");
ftp_login($conn, "USER", "PASS");
$my_file = 'test.txt';
$file_handler = fopen("test.txt", 'w');
fwrite($file_handler, "A second line");
ftp_fput($conn, "/nick/test.txt", $file_handler, FTP_ASCII);
fclose($file_handler);
ftp_close($conn);
?>
```

The file test.txt appears in the correct folder when I run this, but the test.txt file is empty. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried `ftp_fput($conn, "test.txt", $file_handler, FTP_ASCII);`? Since you're accessing it directly in `$file_handler = fopen("test.txt", 'w');` also check file permissions.

Comment: Yep that did it, can you explain what that changes and why it fixes the problem?

Comment: `ftp`? This is 2013, not the 70th!

Comment: Because file writes usually don't use absolute paths, but relative paths when accessed directly. Glad to see it worked for you, cheers.

Comment: @arkascha what do you recommend instead? SSH?

Comment: Plus, I'm pretty sure you can get rid of all your FTP-related code. It should run without it. @NickChapman That would/could only be useful in using an `if/connected` condition.

Comment: @NickChapman: use sftp (an ssh subprotocol which mimics ftp, but in a secure manner). And if you really cannot spare the poor firewall administrator from the horrors of ftp, then at least use ftps to have the command channel encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so we can close the question properly (instead of having it in the unanswered category):

Remove `/nick/` in:

```
ftp_fput($conn, "/nick/test.txt", $file_handler, FTP_ASCII);
```

You were using an absolute path instead of a relative path.

Code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$conn = ftp_connect("ftp.MYSITE.com") or die("Failed to connect to FTP server");
ftp_login($conn, "USER", "PASS");
$my_file = 'test.txt';
$file_handler = fopen("test.txt", 'w');
fwrite($file_handler, "A second line");
ftp_fput($conn, "test.txt", $file_handler, FTP_ASCII);
fclose($file_handler);
ftp_close($conn);
?>
```

Plus, if you don't need to go through FTP to write to file, you can remove all FTP-related code.

It will run without it.